# Run a command in bash and keep it running until the user choose the no option

Tags: bash, loops

How do I make this work? I'm really trying to learn on my own.
But I'm really not getting this. I want to run a command in the
background and prompt a user whether they would like it to keep running
or not. If not, kill the command. I know I'm missing something. I'm just
not sure what.

**Here's my code:**

```
command > /dev/null 2>&1 &
echo

until [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]] ;
do
    echo
    read -p "Would you like to stop the command [Yy/Nn]? " -n 1 -r 

    # Stop stop the command
    killall -9 command
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little unclear what you want your loop frequency to be, but presuming you just want to block until the user types `Yy`, you can simply start `command` in the background, save its *process ID* (e.g. `PID`) using the bash special variable `$!`. Then simply loop until you get a `Yy` (which in bash, you can simply use the *parameter expansion* `${var,,}` to evaluate `var` in *lower-case*). Upon received a `Yy` answer (using `ans` as the variable to store the response), you could do something similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash

command & >/dev/null 2>&1   # start command in background
cmdpid=$!                   # save the PID of command

ans=
while :; do                 # infinite loop until y or Y
    printf "\nWould you like to stop the command (y/n)? "
    read -n 1 -r ans        # read ans
    [ "${ans,,}" = 'y' ] && break
done
printf "\nkilling proc: %d\n" "$cmdpid"
kill $cmdpid                # kill the PID
```

**Example Use/Output**

(without actually starting `command` above (as I have no clue what it is))

```
$ bash rununtil.sh

Would you like to stop the command (y/n)? k
Would you like to stop the command (y/n)? i
Would you like to stop the command (y/n)? l
Would you like to stop the command (y/n)? l
Would you like to stop the command (y/n)? Y
killing proc
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: David C. Rankin, thank you.  That's basically it. Here's the part I couldn't figure which you've solved:  [ "${ans,,}" = 'y' ] && break  I know the break stops the loop but leaves the script running. Can you please explain the  [ "${ans,,}" = 'y' ] part?  Thanks again. I don't want to just use it without fully understand the whole thing.

Comment: Sure, sorry, that is a *compound command*. It is a lazy persons way of avoiding typing the whole `if [ "${ans,,}" = 'y' ]; then break; fi`.  Basically, a *compound command* provides a `command && next command` where `next command` is only run on successful completion of `command`. In the case above `[...]` is the `test` command (e.g. equivalent is `test "${ans,,}" = 'y' && break`. So if it tests `true` (e.g. `$ans` contains `y` or `Y`) then `break` is executed -- jumping out of the loop and executing the `kill` command before the script ends `:)`

Comment: I'm humbled and grateful.  I'll keep trying to learn this elusive bash thing.  I'm just not adept at any programming but I'll keep truckin'. Thanks again!

Comment: Bash is an amazing shell. There is very little you cannot do with it. It may not be the fastest shell, but what it may lack in speed, it makes up for in features. Not that it is slow either, you can parse/sort a 50K entry array in a blink, but you can do it in 1/2 blink in some others. Good luck with your scripting. See: [**Bash Guide**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) (and all the other links there for a good reference)